# how to define an access for a member of telegram bot?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I want to define some specific access for member of telegram bot.
For example, a user can access some part of a bot.
Is it possible? if yes, how can I do?

Comment: If you know their IP you could set restrictions that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the User-Id of the people communicating with your bot and grant privileges to some Ids.